# Merging uint8 array into uint64 error

Tags: c, bit-shift, uint64

I am trying out this code where I first split a uint64 number into an array of uint8, followed by merging the said array back into the original number.

However when I attempt to print out the number `out`, it seems to return the max value of uint64.

```
uint8 buf[8];
uint64 test = 123456789012;
uint64 out = 0;

Uint64toUint8Arr(buf, test, 0);
out = Uint8ArrtoUint64(buf, 0);
std::cout << "out is " << out << std::endl;
```

where my functions are defined as:

```
void Uint64toUint8Arr (uint8* buf, uint64 var, uint32 lowest_pos)
{
    buf[lowest_pos]     =   (var & 0x00000000000000FF) >> 0 ;
    buf[lowest_pos+1]   =   (var & 0x000000000000FF00) >> 8 ;
    buf[lowest_pos+2]   =   (var & 0x0000000000FF0000) >> 16 ;
    buf[lowest_pos+3]   =   (var & 0x00000000FF000000) >> 24 ;
    buf[lowest_pos+4]   =   (var & 0x000000FF00000000) >> 32 ;
    buf[lowest_pos+5]   =   (var & 0x0000FF0000000000) >> 40 ;
    buf[lowest_pos+6]   =   (var & 0x00FF000000000000) >> 48 ;
    buf[lowest_pos+7]   =   (var & 0xFF00000000000000) >> 56 ;
}

uint64 Uint8ArrtoUint64 (uint8* var, uint32 lowest_pos)
{
    return  (var[lowest_pos+7] << 56) | 
            (var[lowest_pos+6] << 48) |
            (var[lowest_pos+5] << 40) | 
            (var[lowest_pos+4] << 32) |
            (var[lowest_pos+3] << 24) | 
            (var[lowest_pos+2] << 16) |
            (var[lowest_pos+1] << 8)  | 
            (var[lowest_pos]   << 0);
}
```

My question is that did I go wrong in either the way I split or merge the uint64 number? I did a similar function for a uint32 type and it seemed to be ok.

Comment: Note: Challenging to do `std::cout << "out is " << out << std::endl;` in `C`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're shifting `uint8` in `Uint8ArrtoUint64()` function on more than 8 bits. As far as I know it's undefined behavior. Anyway, return value is uint8, so you're "or'ing" eight times eight `uint8` numbers and finally you have only uint8 number, not uint64! You need to cast them to `uint64` first, then shift.

```
uint64 Uint8ArrtoUint64 (uint8* var, uint32 lowest_pos)
{
    return  (((uint64)var[lowest_pos+7]) << 56) | 
            (((uint64)var[lowest_pos+6]) << 48) |
            (((uint64)var[lowest_pos+5]) << 40) | 
            (((uint64)var[lowest_pos+4]) << 32) |
            (((uint64)var[lowest_pos+3]) << 24) | 
            (((uint64)var[lowest_pos+2]) << 16) |
            (((uint64)var[lowest_pos+1]) << 8)  | 
            (((uint64)var[lowest_pos])   << 0);
}
```

**Note:** As [@interjay noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669317/merging-uint8-array-into-uint64-error/25669375?noredirect=1#comment40114832_25669375), shifting operation on uint8 will actually give us uint32. I'm not sure about that, but anyway it's better to mention it.

Comment: The `uint8`s will actually be promoted to `int`, which is probably 32 bits. This explains why the 32 bit version seemed to work while the 64 bit version requires the casts.