# Bit Shifting Issue

Tags: c

I have Little Endian WordHH,WordHL,WordLH,WordLL values and they represent with a,b,c,d

I have this number as a decimal `1234456789` it equals as a hex 0x075BCD15 so I call the function like this :

```
BitShifting(0xCD15,0x075D,0x0000,0x000000)
```

But return value equals = `123587861` Why this happening where is my mistake ?

```
uint64_t BitShifting(uint16_t a,uint16_t b, uint16_t c, uint16_t d)

{
    uint64_t val;                                                                                                    
    val = ((a & 0x000000000000FFFF) | ((b << 16) & 0x00000000FFFF0000) | ((c << 32) & 0x0000FFFF00000000) | ((d << 48) & 0xFFFF000000000000));
    return val;
    
}
```

Comment: You have a typo: `0x075D` should be `0x075B`.

Comment: You will find more bugs if you try to use nonzero values for `c` and `d`.  The expression `c << 32` is evaluated as `int` arithmetic and will overflow when `c != 0`, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge , The fix is `((uint64_t)c) << 32`, right?

Comment: Oh, my god tahnk you. :)

Comment: Yes, that would do it, and likewise for `b,c,d`.  (`b << 16` may also overflow `int` if the high bit of `b` is set.)

Comment: Do you think a better code could be written?

Comment: @Tom Karzes Re "*makes a lot more sense to mask first, then shift.*", Except there's no reason to mask at all.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, unless OP expects to pass values that don't fit into 16 bits, and wants them masked.  But I see the args are declared as `uint16_t`, so yeah, masking is unnecessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why can't you shift a uint16\_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55066827/why-cant-you-shift-a-uint16-t)

Comment: duplicates: [Why must I cast a `uint8_t` to `uint64_t` *before* left-shifting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32228933/995714), [Problem of converting byte order for unsigned 64-bit number in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60457248/995714), [Merging uint8 array into uint64 error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25669317/995714)

Comment: Not duplicate, I want to answer my question I found another method for use. But I didnt answer why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1,234,456,789<sub>10</sub> = 4994,50D5<sub>16</sub>
123,587,861<sub>10</sub> = 75D,CD15<sub>16</sub>
So the correct value is being returned.

Which is not to say there are no problem.

On a machine with a 32-bit `int` type, the values will be promoted to `int` values for the shifts, but shifting by 32 and 64 is undefined behaviour and can't produce the correct result. Also, shifting by 16 is undefined behaviour on such a machine if the most significant bit of the input is set.

This means for common architectures, your code doesn't handle `c != 0` and `d != 0` at all, and `b > 0x7FFF` might not work reliably. To fix this, upcast the inputs to the shift to their final type.

```c
uint64_t BitShifting(uint16_t a, uint16_t b, uint16_t c, uint16_t d) {
   return
      (uint64_t)a       | 
      (uint64_t)b << 16 | 
      (uint64_t)c << 32 |
      (uint64_t)d << 48;
}
```

(The first cast is not actually needed.)

The masks were pointless, so I removed them.

---

Demonstatration of the above working:

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint64_t BitShifting(uint16_t a, uint16_t b, uint16_t c, uint16_t d) {
   return
      (uint64_t)a       | 
      (uint64_t)b << 16 | 
      (uint64_t)c << 32 |
      (uint64_t)d << 48;
}

int main() {
   printf("%016"PRIX64"\n", BitShifting(0xCD15, 0x075B, 0x0000, 0x0000));
   printf("%016"PRIX64"\n", BitShifting(0x0123, 0x4567, 0x89AB, 0xCDEF));
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic a.c -o a && ./a
00000000075BCD15
CDEF89AB45670123
```

Comment: Thank you but when I try with this I get "0" value:
      SerialPrint("%d",BitShifting(0xCD15,0x075B,0x0000 ,0x0000));

Comment: *shrug* Can't comment on `SerialPrint` since I've never seen it. But passing a `uint64_t` to `%d` seems very fishy. With the printf family of functions, `%d` expects an `int`.

Comment: @hobik This answer address the posted problem.  If there are additional problems in code that was not posted, then that's a separate issue.  In that case, I would accept this answer, then create a new post that includes the problem code.

Comment: I want to answer my question, I found another method. How can I share my answer

Comment: Why did you close my question, I dont understand

Comment: People voted to close for two different reasons: 1) The code you provided resulted the correct result. You merely thought it returned the wrong result. 2) The actual problem with the code was answered elsewhere. (See the links in the comments on the question). I got my answer in before the answer was closed.